# Clicking a Google query link logs user out of session

Tags: node.js, google, cookie

I have a curious situation with my NodeJS server: it seems like searching for the website on Google signs out the user.

The homepage is `https://emocoes.org/pt/inicio`. I sign in to the website and the homepage shows the version for users, such as a "Content list" button.

I open a new tab, search for the website on Google and click the link. Now the homepage no longer shows the version for users. It's as if I had signed out. When I refresh the first tab with the member version of the homepage, it also shows the public version. I checked that the cookie for session in the session store still exists.

The URL from the Google query is:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjC2J3D65H4AhX5Q_EDHRpnCvoQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Femocoes.org%2Fpt%2Finicio&usg=AOvVaw15-Ef1H79pA6DxaHMLJfgC

I do not see any issue in this link.

I added this tracing to the server's route for the homepage:

```
router.get("/pt/inicio", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("URL = %o", req.originalUrl);
  console.log("query = %o", req.query);
  console.log("User = %o", req.user);
  // The result after the Google URL is:
  //[2022-06-03T17:40:21.308Z] URL = '/pt/inicio'
  //[2022-06-03T17:40:21.308Z] query = {}
  //[2022-06-03T17:40:21.309Z] User = undefined
  ...
});
```

Since the session exists in the MongoDB store, it's as if clicking the Google link deletes the cookie in the browser. I use Safari on macOS and the same thing happens to users on Windows and Google Chrome.

How can I debug this issue?

P.S.: If you want to try it yourself, create a temporary email address at dispostable.com and use it to create an account at https://emocoes.org/en/entrar .

### Update

The NodeJS server code setting the cookie is:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);

const max_session_ms = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

app.use(
  session({
    cookie: {
      maxAge: max_session_ms,
      sameSite: "strict",
    },
    store: store,
    secret: ...,
    signed: true,
    resave: false,  // Unknown effect. See https://github.com/expressjs/session#resave
    saveUninitialized: false,  // Save only explicitly, e.g. when logging in.
    httpOnly: true,  // Don't let browser javascript access cookies.
    secure: true
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this problem seems to be that your site sets the session cookie with `SameSite=Strict`.

The cookie `SameSite` attribute is a security feature which you may need if your site has tight security requirements. You should probably not bother with it, and leave it unset, if it doesn't. When `SameSite` is `Strict` and you click a link on another site that leads to your site, the browser will not send the cookie. When `Lax`, it will send the cookie when clicking on a link, but it will not send it when another site embeds images from your site, for example. More information is available in the [relevant MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) and in [the draft standard for cookies](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-10.html) (scattered over several sections, such as 5.2, 5.4.7, and 8.8).

If you use `Strict`, you must be prepared for strange things to happen. While it looks strange that following a link on one tab affects the reloading on another tab, this has to do with whether reloading is considered to be "same site". [Section 8.8.5 of the draft standard](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-10.html#name-same-site-and-cross-site-re/) defines the rules for that, which are complicated and their implementation could differ between browsers.

When I use Internet banking, I am logged out whenever I do anything slightly out of the ordinary. As far as I can see my banks don't use `SameSite=Strict`, but the example shows that sites with high security are very picky.

Comment: Good hint. Could you explain a bit more? As it is, it is probably not the only reason. First, it does not explain why the user gets logged out when they make a direct request, e.g. when they refresh a page where they were previously logged in. Second, I changed the code from `strict` to `lax` (I updated the question with the relevant code) and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Are you certain about still having the same problem? I can't reproduce the problem any more on Firefox.

Comment: Indeed, now that I try again, I cannot reproduce it either. Maybe it was some immediate caching issue. I updated the question again with `sameSite` to `strict`.